# "The argument is invalid." When Installing IPA from iPhone Configuration Utility

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipcu

When I try to install my IPA from iPhone Configuration Utility, I get a "The argument is invalid." dialog. I cleared the console before installing, and there was no change in the console. This happens on iOS6.1 on an iPod Touch 5 and an iPad 3 as well as on iOS7b6 on an iPod Touch 5.

[image: "The argument is invalid." dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My IPA had an invalid symlink. Xcode actually has a warning for this, but it is very easy to miss.

[image: Xcode Invalid IPA Warning]